# Trying to create a joint table in MySQL but foreign key does not work

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

This is what I have tried:

```
create table books(bcode int(5) primary key, bname varchar(45));
```

and

```
create table customers(cid int(4), cname varchar(20), cadd varchar(40), bcode, 
varchar(45), foreign key(bcode) references books(bcode));
```

After executing the second statement, the following error shows up:

```
ERROR 1215 (HY000): Cannot add foreign key constraint
```

I'm having trouble coming up with a solution. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You haven’t specified a data type for bcode. Specify it and see if it helps.

Comment: Don't impose deadlines on people answering questions on this site. This site is run by volunteers who are trying to help people. You can't guarantee that someone will answer by your deadline and adding "urgent help" comments makes it more likely for you to receive downvotes as it isn't relevant to the question.

Comment: Not related to the question, but you should define a primary key in the second table `costumers`, like `cid` as primary key, since logically, each table should have a primary key so that two records could be easily distinguished.

Answer (score 3):

In the first table books you use bcode as integer 
But in the second table you use bcode as varchar,

So, right one is

```
create table customers(cid int(4), cname varchar(20), cadd varchar(40), bcode
int(5), foreign key(bcode) references books(bcode));
```